# How exactly is SELECT blah, blah FROM table stored in a python file

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

```
query_string = 'SELECT item_id, item_name, description, item_price FROM valve_list'
```

* valve_list is a database table.

The code above is in a python file, how exactly does it stores the data? is it a list containing a list for each item in my database table? like this?

```
query_string = [[item_id, item_name, description, item_price], [item_id, item_name, description, item_price], [item_id, item_name, description, item_price], [item_id, item_name, description, item_price]]
```

How exactly is this stored?

Comment: Python is not SQL

Comment: query is not sql, but in this case this is on a flask/python/html project that has all the imports done, this is on my routes file and a python variable equals to a query string is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

At the moment "query_string" is just a var. You typically need to pass the string to an object which has a connection to a database and executes on the database, typically a cursor. The cursor fetches a result set which can be iterated over to produce the database output.